# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, label, video-capture

Please, anyone, help me. I want to take images in 5 different folders. When I try to take the photo, I am facing this error. I have already made five folders as labels inside my directory. I use Jupiter notebook and webcam.

```
for label in labels:
   !mkdir {'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages\\'+label}
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
   time.sleep(5)
   for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       imagename = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label. label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
       cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
       cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
       time.sleep(2)
    
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
   cap.release()

 ###error
Collecting images for hello
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8924/573635596.py in <module>
  8     for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
  9         ret, frame = cap.read()
 ---> 10         imagename = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label. 
label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
 11         cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
 12         cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'label.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
imagename = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label. label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
```

with

```
imagename = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label, label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))) 
// use comma.
```

Comment: Thank you so much; now it's working.